# What's the difference between LDAP v2 and v3 in terms of architecture

Tags: ldap

Could anyone briefly explain to me is there any difference in terms of architecture for v2 and v3? I know there are some new features added in v3. But in terms of architecture, is v2 also a client and server model?

From this [link](http://www.isode.com/whitepapers/ic-6032.html) it seem that v2 is not a client server model. But from another [link](http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/tutorial/ldap/models/v2.html) it states that

> The protocol consists of the client's sending requests to the server, to which the server responds, though not necessarily in the same order in which the requests were sent

which sounds to me v2 is like a client server model.

Would really appreciate if anyone would enlighten me. Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both LDAP V2 and V3 are client server models.  I would ignore that first link you found.

Having said that, is there even a shipping LDAP V2 server anymore?  Every LDAP instance I have ever seen in the past 5 years has been LDAP V3.

Comment: Hi geoffc, 

Thanks for your reply again. :) It is out of curiosity what's the difference between v2 and v3. Further more, the 1st link contradicts with the rest of the web sites that i have seen. 

Thanks for the enlightenment

Answer (score 9):

Among other things, LDAPv3 introduced UTF-8 values encoding and SASL authentication. LDAPv2 is legacy now and [not recommend to use](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3494) since 2003.